# Can anyone help me understand this SQL code?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, but familiar with Python. I'm trying to import this code to Python but I want to understand what kind of data it captures first...

Can anyone explain to me what this query does? Specially the LAG, OVER, and PARTITION BY functions? Thank you so much!

```
SELECT y.id, y.obs_date, y.imp_vol, LAG (obs_date,1) 
    over (Partition by id ORDER BY y.obs_date asc) as prev_obs_date, LAG (y.imp_vol,1) 
    over (partition by id ORDER BY y.obs_date asc) as prev_imp_vol,imp_vol - LAG (y.imp_vol,1) 
    over (partition by id ORDER BY y.obs_date asc) as absolute_change                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
FROM DMX.MDS_RS_OBS_EQUITY_VOL y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
WHERE y.obs_date > sysdate - 15                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
ORDER BY id desc, obs_date desc
```

Comment: In case it helps you find the answer yourself, the name for this syntax is "window functions"

Comment: Alright thank you so much!!

Comment: Lag finds value of a column in previous record ( ` , 1 ` ), making sure that this record has the same `id` as current record, and orders records in each group of `id` by `obs_date` so it knows what __previous__ mean..

Answer (score 0):

LAG is used for retrieve the previous value.
The OVER part specifies the window (think of it like a subtable of your main table).
When you talk about a previous value, you don't want to compare multiple ids so you PARTITION by ID. This way, each "subtable" contains a single id.

When you talk about a previous value, the ordering is also important and that is what the ORDER BY solves. You order each "subtable" that contains a single id by obs_date.

What the query does is explained by the column aliases.

- prev_obs_date - the previous obs_date (for the current_id)
- prev_imp_vol - the previous imp_vol (for the current_id)
- absolute_change - the difference between  the current imp_vol  and
  the previous imp_vol

The 1 in `LAG(x,1)` specifies that is the previous value by a distance of 1. If you have a table containing 1,2,3,4,5 this is what different attributes of lag would return

```
id  LAG(id,1)   LAG(id,2)   LAG(id,3)
1   NULL        NULL        NULL
2   1           NULL        NULL
3   2           1           NULL
4   3           2           1
5   4           3           2
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much. This is really helpful